# PlusClient.OnPersonLoadedListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services

I get error `PlusClient.OnPersonLoadedListener cannot be resolved to a type`. Below is the line where I use `PlusClient.OnPersonLoadedListener`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, OnClickListener,
        PlusClient.OnPersonLoadedListener...
```

I have perfectly added `google play services lib` to my project. I can say this because I use it with Google maps v2 and that works fine.

I also get errors `loadPerson is undefined for type PlusClient` at line

```
mPlusClient.loadPerson(this, "me");
```

and error `remove @overridden` at line

```
@Override
public void onPersonLoaded(ConnectionResult status, Person person) {...}
```

Any idea why I get this?

Comment: The documentation has been update to correct this problem. Thanks for your report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `OnPersonLoadedListener` and `loadPerson` aren't functions/members

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html

It's `OnPeopleLoadedListener` and `loadPeople`

Comment: oops, its people not person :P